# Click an ASP.NET Button (locate inside an UpdatePanel) to clear a TextBox (locate outside of the UpdatePanel)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am new with java script. I searched to find a way to Click a Button which is inside an UpdatePanel  to clear a TextBox which is located outside of an UpdatePanel. and find this code which work fine. But I want to know how may I get the The javascript code? Here is the code (VB.NET):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.[GetType](), "myScript", "document.getElementById('" + TextBox2.ClientID & "').value = '';", True)
```

The secoud question: I know javascript runs client side but Asp.net is server side. What happens if I use the above code in my page?

Answer (score 0):

For doing this thing using JavaScript on client side you can do something like this-

```
<script>
function clearText(){
   document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").value = '';
}
</script>
```

And on the buttton's `ClientClick` event call the above function. Hope this will solve your problem.